# Model averaging a GLM function with equal weights

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, model-averaging

## Background

Let me first say that I read [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/362331/for-model-averaging-a-glm-do-we-average-the-predictions-on-the-link-or-response) and that I looked at the `BMS` [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BMS/vignettes/bms.pdf).

I used the package `sure` ([CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sure/), [R journal](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2018/RJ-2018-004/RJ-2018-004.pdf#section.2.2)), to calculate surrogate residuals of a `polr` with `resids` (see data below).* The problem is that these surrogate residuals require sampling from a continuous distribution; consequently, the result will be different with every call to resids (they don't converge from bootstrapping the residuals). **If you run my example code, you will see that the result will be different every time you rerun it.** I thought I could temporarily circumvent this issue, by using some form of averaging (for example Bayesian Model Averaging), until I find the solution for my [overarching issue](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/519852/how-to-do-a-control-function-cf-two-stage-residual-inclusion-2sri-with-an).

The goal would be to provide the reader a range for the variable of interest (because my regression output changes every time, it would be kind of weird to just report one output).

## Question

So what I want to do is simple. I want to more or less run the regression 10 times (or one hundred times), and combine or average the outcomes. I thought I could use Bayesian Model Averaging for this. However, from the example they give I have not really been able to figure out what to do.

Essentially I just want to run exactly the same regression 10-100 times and take the average of all the values.

**To repeat: The point is that, because the residual is different every time I run the glm, the outcome of the coefficient of interest is different. For that reason I would like to report and average of running this regression 10-100 times**

I am aware (now) that this is perhaps a bit of a shoe horn approach. Nevertheless, until I find another solution, this the best way I can think of to report my output. I will obviously mention that this is not the most sound way to do it (I have already made a [new post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/519852/how-to-do-a-control-function-cf-two-stage-residual-inclusion-2sri-with-an) describing my overarching issue)

## DATA

```
library(sure) # for residual function and sample data sets
library(MASS) # for polr function

df1 <- df1
df1$z1 <- df1$x
df1$x <- NULL
df1$x <- df2$y
df1$z2 <- df2$x
df1$y <- df3$x/10

mod1 <- polr(as.ordered(x) ~ z1 + z2, data=df1, method='probit')
df1$residuals <- resids(mod1, nsim=100, method="latent")
mod2 <- glm(y ~ x + residuals + z1 + z2, family="quasibinomial", data=df1)
summary(mod2)
```

.*The package is based on [this paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/01621459.2017.1292915), in the Journal of the American Statistical Association.

## EDIT (an attempt at averaging three models):

I tried to do the following:

```
library(MuMIn) # https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MuMIn/MuMIn.pdf

df1$residuals <- resids(mod1, nsim=100, method="latent")
mod2a <- glm(y ~ x + residuals + z1 + z2, family="quasibinomial", data=df1)
summary(mod2a)

df1$residuals <- resids(mod1, nsim=100, method="latent")
mod2b <- glm(y ~ x + residuals + z1 + z2, family="quasibinomial", data=df1)
summary(mod2b)

df1$residuals <- resids(mod1, nsim=100, method="latent")
mod2c <- glm(y ~ x + residuals + z1 + z2, family="quasibinomial", data=df1)
summary(mod2c)

modellist <- list(mod2a, mod2b, mod2c)

summary(model.avg(modellist))
```

Is that the correct way to do it? It worked when I used `lm` instead of `glm` but now all output is `NA`.

```
Model-averaged coefficients: (87 not defined because of singularities in all component models)
```

## With lm instead of glm

```
df1$residuals <- resids(mod1, nsim=100, method="latent")
mod2a <- lm(y ~ x + residuals + z1 + z2, data=df1)
summary(mod2a)

df1$residuals <- resids(mod1, nsim=100, method="latent")
mod2b <- lm(y ~ x + residuals + z1 + z2, data=df1)
summary(mod2b)

df1$residuals <- resids(mod1, nsim=100, method="latent")
mod2c <- lm(y ~ x + residuals + z1 + z2, data=df1)
summary(mod2c)

modellist <- list(mod2a, mod2b, mod2c)

summary(model.avg(modellist))


Call:
model.avg(object = modellist)

Component model call: 
lm(formula = y ~ x + residuals + z1 + z2, data = df1)

Component models: 
      df logLik     AICc delta weight
1234b  8 651.69 -1287.30  0.00   0.86
1234a  8 649.68 -1283.29  4.01   0.12
1234c  8 648.08 -1280.09  7.21   0.02

Term codes: 
residuals         x        z1        z2 
        1         2         3         4 

Model-averaged coefficients:  
(full average) 
              Estimate Std. Error Adjusted SE z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  0.3939836  0.0188525   0.0188639  20.886  < 2e-16 ***
x.L         -0.0944743  0.0386522   0.0386739   2.443  0.01457 *  
x.Q         -0.0007507  0.0180071   0.0180181   0.042  0.96677    
x.C          0.0252203  0.0140922   0.0141008   1.789  0.07368 .  
x^4         -0.0008289  0.0093890   0.0093947   0.088  0.92970    
residuals    0.0240304  0.0089833   0.0089882   2.674  0.00751 ** 
z1.L         0.0000000  0.0000000   0.0000000      NA       NA    
z1.Q         0.0000000  0.0000000   0.0000000      NA       NA    
z1.C         0.0000000  0.0000000   0.0000000      NA       NA    
z1^4         0.0000000  0.0000000   0.0000000      NA       NA    
z2           0.0026400  0.0032725   0.0032745   0.806  0.42012    
 
(conditional average) 
              Estimate Std. Error Adjusted SE z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  0.3939836  0.0188525   0.0188639  20.886  < 2e-16 ***
x.L         -0.0944743  0.0386522   0.0386739   2.443  0.01457 *  
x.Q         -0.0007507  0.0180071   0.0180181   0.042  0.96677    
x.C          0.0252203  0.0140922   0.0141008   1.789  0.07368 .  
x^4         -0.0008289  0.0093890   0.0093947   0.088  0.92970    
residuals    0.0240304  0.0089833   0.0089882   2.674  0.00751 ** 
z1.L                NA         NA          NA      NA       NA    
z1.Q                NA         NA          NA      NA       NA    
z1.C                NA         NA          NA      NA       NA    
z1^4                NA         NA          NA      NA       NA    
z2           0.0026400  0.0032725   0.0032745   0.806  0.42012    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: you don't have to use Bayesian model averaging for this, since you are running the same regression, you can just average the models with equal weights

Comment: @rep_ho Thank you very much for your comment. Do you know of any package that does this?

Comment: This looks a little bit like a request for code help, which people may consider off topic. Can you clarify the statistical question / *that* this is a statistical question?

Comment: Can you clarify why you're doing this?  Why do you need to average the residuals? What is the larger goal here?

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica I get your point. It started out as a purely statistical question without any code. I just simply want to know how to solve my problem of averaging a coupl of glm's. Then I started reporting what I had been trying..

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica Isn't it clear from the first two paragraphs? I have an unstable residual in the model because of which the outcome of the model changes all the time. Because I cannot just report a random outcome, I want to average the outcomes, and report that.

Comment: lol. I understand your frustration, @Tom. You try to make it better 1 way, then someone comes along & complains about that. "You can please some of the people..."

Comment: We don't actually have your data. I don't see why you would get different outcomes if you run `polr` on the same dataset multiple times. I do.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica It's because the residual calculated by the `sure` package produces a different residual each time. This part: "these surrogate residuals require sampling from a continuous distribution; consequently, the result will be different with every call to resids" is straight from the explanation of the package.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica You can actually try to run my example code, it will give you different outputs..

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is the larger point, here? Reading your code more carefully, I'm guessing you want to assess something like a mediation model, where the mediator is ordinal. Is that the ultimate goal?

Comment: It sounds to me like the problem you're trying to solve is `<X>`, and you're wondering
if `<Y>` is a good way to go about it. Is that fair? Because if your real question
is "`<X>`?" then I would suggest only asking about that. As its written right now, 
the question appears to be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: I am trying to apply a Control Function (CF)/Two Stage Residual Inclusion (2SRI) to a function which has non-linear dependent variable and an ordinal endogenous variable.

Comment: I would suggest you ask about that, rather than a broken attempt to shoehorn it.

Comment: Hahaha, I get your point now. I will make a new question.

Comment: I am just a little bit scared that I won't get a proper or any answer to that.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica  I made a new question (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/519852/how-can-i-overcome-non-converging-residuals-when-using-a-control-function-cf). Is this question better? Also: Any suggestion for a better title?