# How flexible is Stata's ivpois? Could I use it for a (quasi) binomial distribution?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, stata, quasi-likelihood

According to [this post](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1308457-endogeneity-issue-negative-binomial) on statalist, Stata's `ivpois` (an instrumental variable approach) is pretty flexible, with very little assumptions.

The problem mentioned in the post is:

"I have a database with counts as dependent variable. This variable suffers from over-dispersion problem."

Wooldridge mentions:

"I would strongly recommend trying IVPOIS, too. Regrettably, this command name is a misnomer. It should be called something like IVEXPON, as it works for any exponential model with multiplicative error. It does not care whether the EEV is continuous or discrete, so it produces consistent estimators under much weaker assumptions."

My thought was, if it works for any exponential model, does that mean it also works for my model, which is technically a `quasibinomial`, but according to [this fine post](https://m-clark.github.io/posts/2019-08-20-fractional-regression/), that boils down to a `binomial` with robust standard errors?

Hence my question: How flexible is Stata's ivpois? Could I use it for a (quasi) binomial distribution?

Background: [How to do a Control Function (CF) / Two Stage Residual Inclusion (2SRI) with an ordinal dependent variable in the first stage and a glm in the second](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/519852/how-to-do-a-control-function-cf-two-stage-residual-inclusion-2sri-with-an)

Comment: Are you thinking of using the number of trials as an exposure variable?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov In all honesty, I don't even really understand your question. I am not very familiar with this terminology (I tried to look up what it means, but I am still not sure haha). My question is more about me not really understanding for what type of distributions `ivpois` can be used (the background is that I am desperately looking for a direct 2SLS approach that is defendable for my problem: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/519852/how-to-do-a-control-function-cf-two-stage-residual-inclusion-2sri-with-an

Comment: in binomial regression, you know the number of successful trials as well as number of failures, and you use both. in poisson regression you have a number of events and a variable measuring exposure, wich is conceptually similar, but also quite different

Comment: @carlo Thank you for your comment. The thing is that `ivpois` is not actually (only) a poisson regression (see the link in the post).